I am a little confused by how does `gghighlight` work with non-logical (min / max) predicates
I don't understand how these plots differ from each other. I tweaked around with min, max, -min, and -max. But I don't really understand how and what these do!
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)
library(patchwork)


A <- ggplot(d, aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  gghighlight(max(value), max_highlight = 5L)

B <- ggplot(d, aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  gghighlight(-max(value), max_highlight = 5L)

C <- ggplot(d, aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  gghighlight(min(value), max_highlight = 5L)

D <- ggplot(d, aes(idx, value, colour = type)) +
  geom_line() +
  gghighlight(-min(value), max_highlight = 5L)

(A + B) / (C + D) + patchwork::plot_annotation(tag_levels = "A")



So I thought more about the question and here is the answer:

Plot A highlights the lines with maximums of the top 5.
Plot B highlights the lines with maximums of the bottom 5.
Plot C highlights the lines with minimums of the top 5.
Plot D highlights the lines with minimums of the bottom 5.

